# How TFS integrates with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, visual-sourcesafe

I am looking to migrate some databases out of Visual Source Safe (VSS) and into Team Foundation Server (TFS). I know I am able to migrate from VSS to SVN, and then from SVN to TFS using a few tools that I have found (either free or purchased). The aim is to get the source code into TFS and then integrate the project with SharePoint so that various documents can be accessed from there.

How easy is it to set up TFS to integrate with SharePoint? What do I need to do?

What documents/files can/will be added to SharePoint? Does TFS choose for me or can I select what I want to appear in SharePoint?

Any examples or information on how TFS integrates with SharePoint would be appriciated.

Comment: You can migrate directly from VSS to TFS, you don't need to migrate to SVN first. See the walkthrough at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181247.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instances are separate.  The files stored in SharePoint are not in the version control library and vice-versa.  There is a web interface to the source control library available outside of SharePoint.

Each Team Project in TFS has an associated SharePoint portal.  What we do is version control all of our software in TFS, and store all of our documentation in the SharePoint portal that corresponds to the team project.  We made sure to turn version control *on* within SharePoint so we can retrieve previous versions.

On the odd occasion that we do need to version control documentation alongside the source code (for audit reasons), we will store that in a documentation folder within TFS.